Solving a Linear System with 5 Equations and 6 Variables
Variables $a,b,c,d,e,f$ are real numbers such that:
$$\begin{align} &a+b+c+d+e+f=0 \\ &a+2b+3c+4d+2e+2f=0 \\ &a+3b+6c+9d +4e +6f=0 \\ &a+4b+10c+16d+8e+24f=0 \\ &a+5b+15c +25d+16e+120f=42\end{align}$$
then the question is to find the sum of digits of $a+6b+21c+36d+32e+720f$.
My attempt: I tried subtracting, and solving using matrix, but can't solve further. Any hints would help a lot. To elaborate, from subtracting equation $5$ and $4$, $4$ and $3$, $3$ and $2$, and $4-3-2$ and  $3-2-1$ , I was able to reduce: $a=28f$, $e=\frac{13f}5$, $a= \frac{84e}{13}$ but cannot solve further.

Please don't use pictures of text or formulas. See
here,
why. Use MathJax. Here is a
tutorial.

I have included my attempt

Interestingly, we have each LHS is of the form $a+nb+ \frac{n(n+1)}2 c + n^2 d + 2^{n-1} e+ n!f$.

Is it ok now? I elaborated my attempt

I noticed that too. How does it help in solving?

Although the number of equations and variables makes the calculation by hand rather tedious, this is a straightforward application of Gaussian elimination.
One shortcut would be to add one more variable, let's call it $g$, and one more equation:
$$
a+6b+21c+36d+32e+720f-g = 0
$$
There is one free variable, but once you solve the system, you will see $g$ does not depend on it.

This, along with most linear systems, can be solved using Gaussian Elimination. It can be applied here resulting in the following matrix:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 8 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & -6 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 8 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & -11 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
With the matrix in reduced row echelon form, you can derive the values of each variable and then plug them in to find the sum of $a+6b+21c+36d+32e+720f$
